# Trello API get card comments

Tags: api, trello

is there a way to get all the comments of a card through the Trello API? I can get the card, the list which it is in, the members assigned to it etc. but can't see a way to get the comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Comments are a type of action ("commentCard"), so look into the /card/:id/actions

Comment: Thanks, will get that going with this, any chance of doing it a bit easier like /card/id/comments ?

Comment: Did you figure out if this works? I only see API calls for PUT/POST/DELETE comments.

Comment: In Ruby, using the [ruby-trello](https://github.com/jeremytregunna/ruby-trello) gem, I'm able to get `commentCard` actions straight from a `Card` object with `comments = card.actions({filter: 'commentCard'})`. I *think* it still makes a separate HTTP request but it may make more sense to do this way if you already have an object on hand. I expect there are similar things you can do with other languages' APIs.

Answer (score 7):

Try this API URL

Method: `GET`

[https://api.trello.com/1/cards/{card_Id}/actions?filter=commentCard&key={trellokey}&token={trellotoken}](https://api.trello.com/1/cards/%7Bcard_Id%7D/actions?filter=commentCard&key=%7Btrellokey%7D&token=%7Btrellotoken%7D)

Answer (score 2):

GET /1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/actions

you'll get list of action-objects in json, each has its type, type for comment "commentCard",
comment text in

```
object.data.text
```

https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html#get-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-actions

Answer (score 0):

```
Trello.actions.get(action.id + "/data", function() {})
```

seems to do it for me with client.js. Hope that helps :)